# MySQL bitwise operators in Sequel gem

Tags: mysql, ruby, sequel

I am trying to work with bitwise operators using the Sequel gem and I was wondering if there was a natively supported way to do this.
Right now what I can do of course is

```
MySequelModel.where('bitcolumn & ?', '0001010')
```

However, what I am doing is merging a lot of sequel expressions that I have generated, a bit like so:

```
sequel_query = queries.inject(Neutral) do |expression, a_hash|
  expression & generate_query_from(a_hash)
end
```

`generate_query_from(...)` would then always return a Sequel Expression object. Now this will of course not work anymore when a possible return value could also be `"bitcolumn & '100010'"` instead.

I tried creating a Sequel expresison like `Sequel.expr("bitcolumn & '10001'")` or `Sequel.expr(:bit_column) & Sequel.expr(value)` but that both causes a Sequel::Error: Invalid filter expression even though the latter works using the > etc operators.

UPDATE:
Interestingly, it is actually possible to merge a Sequel expression with a query string, however it does not create the "correct" query. Instead of creating e.g:

```
"SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE ((`bitcolumn` = '000001') AND bitcolumn & '000001')"
```

it creates:

```
"SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE ((`bitcolumn` = '000001') AND 'bitcolumn & \\'000001\\'')"
```

which doesn't work.

But maybe my usage: `Sequel.expr(bitcolumn: '000001') & "bitcolumn & '000001'"` is not correct and could be fixed. 
Additionally if my first returned query is a string: `query_string & sequel_expression` will of course fail.

UPDATE 2:

I now found http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/sql_rdoc.html#label-Bitwise+Mathematical+Operators+-28-26+-7C+-5E+-3C-3C+-3E-3E+-7E-29 which seems like the most appropriate thing, but doing:

```
[54] pry(main)> exp = Sequel.expr(:bit_column).sql_number & 1
=> #<Sequel::SQL::NumericExpression @op=>:&, @args=>[#<Sequel::SQL::Identifier @value=>"bit_column">, 1]>
[55] pry(main)> User.where(exp).sql
```

causes an error as well

```
Sequel::Error: Invalid filter expression: #<Sequel::SQL::NumericExpression @op=>:&, @args=>[#<Sequel::SQL::Identifier @value=>"bit_column">, 1]>
```

Comment: I believe this `Sequel.expr(:bit_column).sql_number & 1` can be `Sequel[:bit_column].sql_number & 1` instead and should create `"bit_column" & 1` [Sequel Docs for Bitwise operators](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel/blob/master/doc/sql.rdoc#bitwise-mathematical-operators------)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I managed to get this working by using Sequel.lit.
`Sequel.lit("bit_column & 1") & Sequel.expr('bit_column' => 1)` returns `"SELECT * FROM 'users' WHERE (cars_owned & 20 AND ('device' = 8))"` and that is  the correct query and works.

I'm still sure that there's a better way using proper bitwise mathematical operators, so I'm gonna keep this open.